# Quickest way to reduce a sequential index of values to a set of sequential ranges for each value in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a large Panda Dataframe, where the index is consecutive integers. The column corresponds to a value at that posistion, a toy example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(index=range(7),data = [1.3,1.3,1.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,1.3], columns=['Values'])
     Values
0    1.3
1    1.3
2    1.3
3    0.4
4    0.6
5    0.6
6    1.3
```

Is there a quick way to reduce this to a set of sequential ranges instead:

```
start    end    Values
0        3        1.3
3        4        0.4
4        6        0.6
6        7        1.3
```

I have ruled out iterating row by row as far too slow. Taking some inspiration from this [answer in Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/grouping-consecutive-numbers-into-ranges-in-python-3-2), I have used an enumerate + groupby pattern on each unique value:

```
for val in set(a['Values'].values):
    index = list(a[list(a['Values'] == val)].index.values)
    for _, g in groupby(index, key=lambda n, c=count(): n-next(c)):
        l = list(g)
        print(l[0], l[-1]+1, val)

3    4    0.4
0    3    1.3
6    7    1.3
4    6    0.6
```

Which I can then store and sort. Is there anyway to improve this for better performance in python?

Comment: why do you expect end at 7 for the last row when index 7 isnot present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `groupby` key with `diff` and `cumsum` , the do `groupby`

```
b=a.reset_index().groupby(a.Values.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).\
      agg(start=('index','min'),
          end=('index',lambda x : x.max()+1),
          Values=('Values','first'))
        start  end  Values
Values                    
1           0    3     1.3
2           3    4     0.4
3           4    6     0.6
4           6    7     1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper series and group with `idxmin` and `idxmax`:

```
s = a['Values'].ne(a['Values'].shift()).cumsum().rename(None)
d = dict(zip(['idxmin','idxmax'],['start','end']))

a.groupby([s,'Values'])['Values'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).rename(columns=d)
```

---

```
           start  end
  Values            
1 1.3         0    0
2 0.4         3    3
3 0.6         4    4
4 1.3         6    6
```

Note that this doesn't give the end as 7 for th elast Value `1.3` since that index is not present in the dataframe.